# R: Grouped barplot of proportions of character variables with error bars

Tags: r, image, graph, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot of the proportions of observations in different groups corresponding to different values in a character vector, including error bars for the proportions.

A minimal working example of the data I have is found below:

```
# Observations belong to group 'a' or 'b'
group <- c("a","a","b","b","b","a", "a")

# Each observation can take on values of "low", "med", or "high"
values <- c("low","low","low","high","med","high", "high")

# My data is a single data frame
dat <- data.frame(as.character(group), as.character(values))
```

As we can see in the above:

- Group 'a' is comprised of 4 total observations: 2 observations of value "low" (50%) and 2 observations of value "high" (50%).
- Group 'b' is comprised of 3 total observations: 1 observation of value "low" (33%), 1 observation of value "med" (33%), and 1 observation of value "high" (33%).

I am trying to create a plot where the X-axis is each of the possible values (low, med, high) found in the 'values' vector and the Y-axis is the *proportion* of that respective . A different bar is presented for each of the possible values of the 'group' vector and for each of the possible values group members could have reported. Error bars are included in the image. I am having difficulty figuring out how to calculate the proportions with the error bars and including the proportions in the figure in ggplot.

[image]

Comment: `
ggplot(dat, aes(values)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = group), position = "dodge") `

Comment: This [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30967643/4752675) provides an answer.

Comment: The SO question provides an answer once one already has the data in a specific format. Analysisparalysis provided a comprehensive answer I'll confirm as the answer once receiving a response on my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to go about that. The error bars are really big with the example data you gave because there is only one observation in several of those groups.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data_frame(group, values) %>%
    count(group, values) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(percent = n / sum(n),
           error = sqrt((percent * (1-percent))/n)) %>%
    mutate(values = factor(values, levels = c("low", "med", "high")))

dat

#> Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#> Groups: group [2]
#> 
#>   group values     n   percent     error
#>   <chr> <fctr> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     a   high     2 0.5000000 0.3535534
#> 2     a    low     2 0.5000000 0.3535534
#> 3     b   high     1 0.3333333 0.4714045
#> 4     b    low     1 0.3333333 0.4714045
#> 5     b    med     1 0.3333333 0.4714045


ggplot(dat, aes(values, percent, fill = group)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = percent - error, ymax = percent + error),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: What is  "mutate(id = row_number())" doing here? I don't see where it would be used in the rest of the code. Additionally, I'd recommend the more common formula for errors: 1.96*sqrt((percent * (1-percent))/n)) and a continuity correction of 0.5/n.

Comment: Ah yes, great! I was originally thinking I would need to keep track of which observation each value came from, but then did not. I edited out the line with `row_number()`. And yes, you can define whatever you like for the error bars within `mutate()`.

Comment: group_by(group) makes the n for the subsequent error calculation the n within each group. Is that desirable (instead of n = total number of observations for all groups)? I guess that depends on the kind of confidence interval desired.